# Tips for Aggregating MongoDB Time Trend Data over groups with varying date ranges

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a MongoDB collection with documents like:

```
{'date': 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00, 'population': 110, 'state': 'NY', 'start': 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00, 'end': 2021-05-26T00:00:00.000+00:00},
{'date': 2020-01-02T00:00:00.000+00:00, 'population': 112, 'state': 'NY', 'start': 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00, 'end': 2021-05-26T00:00:00.000+00:00},
...
{'date': 2020-03-15T00:00:00.000+00:00, 'population': 119, 'state': 'NY', 'start': 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00, 'end': 2021-05-26T00:00:00.000+00:00},
{'date': 2020-03-16T00:00:00.000+00:00, 'population': 131, 'state': 'NY', 'start': 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00, 'end': 2021-05-26T00:00:00.000+00:00},
{'date': 2020-03-17T00:00:00.000+00:00, 'population': 138, 'state': 'NY', 'start': 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00, 'end': 2021-05-26T00:00:00.000+00:00},
...
{'date': 2020-03-16T00:00:00.000+00:00, 'population': 31, 'state': 'AL', 'start': 2020-03-16T00:00:00.000+00:00, 'end': 2021-05-24T00:00:00.000+00:00},
{'date': 2020-03-17T00:00:00.000+00:00, 'population': 31, 'state': 'AL', 'start': 2020-03-16T00:00:00.000+00:00, 'end': 2021-05-24T00:00:00.000+00:00},
...
```

Each document represents a date and population in a given locale present in the data, with the first and last recorded dates for that locale present.

I want to be able to visualize aggregate time trends on this data. In this simple example, I would visualize population on the y axis (the sum of all populations on a given date) and date on the x axis. **The issue** is that I need to visualize only a comprehensive set. For instance, since the data for AL only starts on 2020-03-16, I do not want my population visualization to jump up on that date when the new state is added.

I do not want to interpolate backwards in time; I would rather just deduce the viable set over a given time range and aggregate over that comprehensive subset.

Is there a simple way to identify the set of states that have continuous data, and sum population over this, given a start date and an end date?

For instance, if my input was

```
first: '2020-03-16'
last: '2021-05-24'
```

my output would be something like:

```
{'date': 2020-03-16T00:00:00.000+00:00, 'setsize': 2, 'set': ['NY', 'AL'], 'population': 162},
{'date': 2020-03-17T00:00:00.000+00:00, 'setsize': 2, 'set': ['NY', 'AL'], 'population': 169},
...
```

However, if my input was

```
first: '2020-03-15'
last: '2021-05-24'
```

My output would only include NY, because there is no data for AL on the first date, so my output would be

```
{'date': 2020-03-15T00:00:00.000+00:00, 'setsize': 1, 'set': ['NY'], 'population': 119},
{'date': 2020-03-16T00:00:00.000+00:00, 'setsize': 1, 'set': ['NY'], 'population': 131},
{'date': 2020-03-17T00:00:00.000+00:00, 'setsize': 1, 'set': ['NY'], 'population': 138},
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregations

- `$match` to get the documents upon the condition
- `$group` to group by date

Here is the code

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          { $gt: [ "$date", "2020-03-15" ]},
          { $lt: [ "$date", "2021-05-24" ] }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$date",
      "setSize": { "$sum": 1 },
      "set": { $push: "$state" },
      population: { $sum: "$population" }
    }
  }
```

])

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n9lcQga-mlW)**

Note : You havent mentioned the date format. So I take date as string. If you have date format, you can simply convert it to either date-> string or string-> date

Comment: This doesn't appear to be quite what I want. I only ever want the maximum intersection over a time range, so I never want a result to be returned that has different values in the "set" field over its date-array elements.

Comment: May I know whats wrong with the above query, sometimes I can correct it